# Updating a schema bound csv from a collection of json documents

Tags: python, json, excel, csv, flask

I have a collection of JSON documents. I need to aggregate the data from all these documents into a portable format like CSV for easy access to data in excel or other analytics tools.

The problem I face is that I am creating JSON document by adding keys one by one. Because of this all the keys in the JSON get randomized and I'm not sure that when I parse the JSON document into CSV it will retain its schema (not as in RDBMS but the 2d excel schema)

I just want to ensure that when I update the CSV file everytime with csv.writerow() each value should correspond to its header which was set first time.

Any ideas how can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Do you have a piece of code you started to work with, or at least an example of data.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [`csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) to create the CSV file:

```
import json
import csv


# Two JSON documents
jsondoc1 = '''{"a":"aardvark", "b":"bengal tiger"}'''
jsondoc2 = '''{"a":"Samuel Adams", "b":"Carter Braxton"}'''

# Create a CSV file, then use csv.DictWriter() to write the header
# and one for for each JSON document
with open("output.csv", "wt") as output_file:
    output_file = csv.DictWriter(output_file, ["a", "b"])
    output_file.writeheader()
    output_file.writerow(json.loads(jsondoc1))
    output_file.writerow(json.loads(jsondoc2))
```

Result:

```
a,b
aardvark,bengal tiger
Samuel Adams,Carter Braxton
```

Comment: What if the some keys are missing in the document. Some json docs might have 5 keys and some have 6 out of which 4 are identical and rest are distinct. In such case how can I ensure that integrity of csv.